# Rate Control overlaps with Menu items

Tags: 2010, development, web-part, page-layout

On my sharepoint page i have Menu on the top and a sharepoint rating control on the top right side. The onHover event of menu displays a list menu items.
The rate control is added to the layout which is connected to the page and for creating menu i have used Syste.web.ui.webcontrol.menu class.

My problem is when i hover my last menus to open the manu items, the stars on the rate control overlap my menu items but rest part of rate control goes behind my menu items.

For more clarificatio of the scenario i am attachng this image.

[image: Image for better understanding] Image for better understanding

What i want is the menu items open, the rate control should fall behind them. I tried using Z-Index property but it is not working for this rate control.

How to resolve this??

**EDIT**
I just came to know that the problem is with all the sharepoint inbuilt controls.
On one page of mine i have a list view webpart in the range of menu dropdown, and it is behaving in the same way. The listview is visible through the Menu items.

So as of now, i guess all sharepoint 2010 inbuilt controls are visible through menu items.

Comment: The image i uploaded is not displayed.. i will try to upload image to some server and will share the url to the question

Answer (score 0):

The stars of the rating control must have some very high Z-Index. What I would do is to write some script to temporarily hide the Stars when hovering on the menu control.

Comment: but i have tried to set the Z-index of my drop dpwn to high values.....secondly my rating control is added to page layout, so how will i access it my code. If you have any sample code please share, i ll like to give it a try

Comment: It doesn't matter in which sequence a control is added (whether it's on the the master page, page layout or page itself.) Try to find the clientID of the control or set some arbitrary CSS Class on it and then use something like Jquery to Hide it : $('#RatingControlID').hide();